# Why don't the curve control points move along the Y axis?

Tags: bezier-curves, extrude

When I try to extrude a curve, for some reason the extrude makes a flat model instead of extruding the Bezier like a "wall". This might have something to do with the tilt, but I haven't found a proper solution yet.

But in trying to solve the problem, I come up with behavior that I don't understand. So I thought I would ask....

Simplified Scenario:

1. Add Bezier [Shift add - Curve - Bezier]
2. Scale it to get it flat using X axis [s - x - 0 - enter] (perhaps this is the reason for my problem)

After that, I can no longer move a single control point on the Y axis. X and Z work fine. I thought the scaling just moves the vectors of the control points to the same plane and flattens the Bezier curve that way. But somehow it prevents me from moving the Y axis as well.

Comment: You are right, step 2 is a problem.  You are moving the control points to the same place.  So they disappear.

Comment: May I ask what do you mean by "they disappear"? I'm just moving the control points on the same level. Why that prevents me to move the control points after that in one axe?

Comment: The bezier curve has two control points, and they are both positioned along the x axis.  If you move the points to the same position along X they will be in identical locations.  You will not be able to select them individually.

Comment: The bezier handle tilt on the second point is what is creating the slope in the y axis.

Comment: You are also snapping these bezier handles into the same position.

Comment: They are still separate points, just more difficult to select.

Comment: Uuf, no matter how carefully I was trying to describe this, I still failed...

The correct sequence is not scale for along x axle, but y. So it should be like this:
1. Add Bezier [Shift add - Curve - Bezier]
2. Scale it to get it flat using y-axle [s - y - 0 - enter]

After this I lost possibility to move control points to along y-axle.

I'm very sorry about this confuses :(